# How can I know that some property was binding?

Tags: wpf, binding, properties

How can I know that some property was binding?
For example a property (Class implemeted from NotificationObject):

```
public string Title
{
  set
  {
    _title=value;
    this.RaisePropertyChanged(() => this.Title);
  }
  get
  {
    return _title;
  }
}
```

Using:

```
<TextBlock Text={Binding Title}>
```

I need to know when a property is not used by anyone to release dispose resources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no easy way to know if a control is bound to *a specific property* of your ViewModel, but you can know if someone is subscribed to the `PropertyChanged` event (just check if it's not null). The binding engines subscribes to this event, so if something is bound to at least one property of your ViewModel, the `PropertyChanged` event handler won't be null.

Answer (score 1):

You can tell if someone has requested your property by setting a flag, although not sure if this will meet your needs:

```
private bool _isTitleBound = false;

public string Title
{
  set
  {
    _title = value;

    this.RaisePropertyChanged(() => Title);
  }
  get
  {
    _isTitleBound = true;

    return _title;
  }
}
```

You could also consider lazy instantiation, which would result in your disposable objects only being created when the property getter was called. If the property getters are never called, your disposable objects will never be created. Also, if this is a one-time binding consider using lazy instantiation with disposal of your object. For example:

```
public MyThing Thing
{
  get
  {
    MyThing thing = CreateMyThing();

    Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke(
      DispatcherPriority.Background,
      new Action(() => thing.Dispose());

    return thing;
  }
}

private MyThing CreateMyThing()
{
  //create and return MyThing instance;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I not understand, you create (or get) object in this "MyThing thing = CreateMyThing();", and disposed this object (thing) on next step?

Comment: @Ivan Yes the object will be disposed, but at a lower priority than binding and rendering, so it should be bound and displayed before it is disposed. This makes sense if it is a one-time binding i.e. if it has no property changed notifications itself. I would need more information about how your application works if this poses a problem. The first simple flag solution, or lazy instantiation may be useful to you.